# Notepad++ and Dreamweaver - Tab Conversions

Tags: notepad++, web-development, dreamweaver, indentation, line-spacing

I work on a team of developers. Some like to use Dreamweaver but I really do prefer Notepad++. The problem comes whenever we need to edit one anothers files and the tabs don't match up / align (indentation). I'm curious to why this happens and wondering if there was a way in either Dreamweaver settings or Notepad++ settings to convert these tabs into something different so that they match. Is this possible / how?

**Examples**

The top image is simple CSS in Notepad++ and the bottom is code inside Dreamweaver.

[image: Top: Notepad++ - Bottom: Dreamweaver]

The image on the left is Notepad++ Tab Settings which is set to 4. The image on the right is Dreamweaver Code Formatting whose tab is also set to 4.

[image: Left: Notepad++ - Right: Dreamweaver]

The image on the left is Dreamweaver and the image on the right is Notepad++ which look to be using the same font Courier New 10px, though they do not look it.

[image: Left: Dreamweaver - Right: Notepad++]

**Discrepancies**

In the example above, in **Dreamweaver** it seems butting the bracket directly up to the `h6` then `tab` does a double-space instead of a full 4 spaces where **Notepad++** does a "7 space" tab which is very strange.

Comment: What display font are you using in Dreameaver and in Notepad++? In your second image (notepad++?) it doesn't look like a fixed width font ...

Comment: a) Use the same font in both, and b) try turning off the "Indent with 2 spaces" option in Dreamweaver.  Also, can you please make the TAB/whitespace characters visible in the editor(s) and re-do the screenshots (so we can see the actual whitespace characters being inserted)?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I'm not sure how to make the TAB/Whitespace visible in either editor besides highlighting - is there an easier way to do this that would be more helpful?

Comment: Notepad++: View->Show Symbol->Show White Space and TAB.  Dreamweaver: View->Code View Options->Hidden Characters. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 That's cool, thanks! I've updated the first image to the image with the tab / space highlighting.

Comment: Notepad is definitely NOT using a monospaced font in that image.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 IDK that was default - I haven't changed any style settings - this is Global styles / Global overrides so it's being used everywhere by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the problem is with the default styling of Notepad++ for CSS files.

Go to the menu entry of Settings / Style Configurator, then click on CSS and TAG, getting this :

[image: image1]

You will notice that the font used is @Batang (which I personally never heard of or used).
This font does not look like it is a monospace font.

Change the font to the default and click Save & Close :

[image: image2]

Here is the display, where the first image is before and the second after this change :

[image: image3]
[image: image4]

The second image, from after the change, looks now much more like a monospace font.

You could change the fonts some more, to better agree with Dreamweaver.
However, as I do not use it, I do not know what fonts it uses for displaying CSS.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. My globals were Courier New but for whatever reason CSS was different. Now I know I need to check the fonts on a language level to match up with Dreamweaver. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

If you take a close look at the image, you'll notice that Notepad++ is not rendering the monospaced font correctly.  It appears to be an issue with the space character.   See how the `h4` tags don't line up.  Compare that to the Dreamweaver screenshot where all the characters are lined up in neat columns.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11782472/94928) seems to be addressing the same problem, so there may be something in the CSS template file that's causing problems.